# wget - Considers download done after 1 second even though it isn't

Tags: wget, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use wget to download the Raspbian image for the Raspberry Pi (http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/images/raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip).

It starts downloading fine but then finished after a second without error but clearly not finished and leaves a tiny file instead of the full one:

```
kemra102@iacon:~/Downloads$ wget http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/images/raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip
--2012-08-13 20:26:57--  http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/images/raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip
Resolving downloads.raspberrypi.org (downloads.raspberrypi.org)... 94.136.44.110
Connecting to downloads.raspberrypi.org (downloads.raspberrypi.org)|94.136.44.110|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/download.php?file=/images/raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip [following]
--2012-08-13 20:26:57--  http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/download.php?file=/images/raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip
Reusing existing connection to downloads.raspberrypi.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip'

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                             ] 17,012      --.-K/s   in 0.04s   

2012-08-13 20:26:57 (373 KB/s) - `2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip' saved [17012]

kemra102@iacon:~/Downloads$ ls -l 2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kemra102 kemra102 17012 Aug 13 20:26 2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip
kemra102@iacon:~/Downloads$
```

I cannot find anything anywhere on the net to indicate what could possible be causing the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking at the file you've received:

```
$ wget http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/images/raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip
-- snip --
2012-08-13 16:31:23 (9.78 MB/s) - `2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip' saved [6501]

$ file 2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip 
2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip: HTML document text
```

We can see that we're actually receiving an HTML document. This is further evidenced by the line in your output: `Length: unspecified [text/html]`

Note also that when you invoke wget, the server immediately redirects to `http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/download.php?file=/images/raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip` which is indeed a web page.

Try opening either of those links in your browser:

- http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/images/raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip
- http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/download.php?file=/images/raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip

When you do, you get a download information page. There's a direct link to the download on that page. Pass **that** link to wget and you'll be set.

Answer (score 0):

You're wget is being redirected (HTTP status 301): Use the [direct link](http://files.velocix.com/c1410/images/raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian/2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.zip) instead.